# How do you get a CNAME record's authoritative TTL value in node.js?

Tags: node.js, caching, dns, cname, ttl

I'm building a DNS record checker in node.js, and am using [native-dns](https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns), a package that extends the native node DNS functionality.

I want to get the authoritative answer for CNAME ttl, which you can get with [dig +trace](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-dig-to-find-dns-time-to-live-ttl-values/):

```
dig +trace +nocmd +noall +answer +ttlid a www.google.com
```

The ttl that native-dns returns is a cached value, so it decreases over time and eventually resets. I've tried setting the Platform cache to false, like so:

```
var dns = require('native-dns')
dns.platform.cache = false
```

And setting the individual Request cache to false, like so:

```
var dnsReq = dns.Request({
  header: {aa: 1},
  question: question,
  server: {address: '8.8.8.8'},
  cache: false
})
```

Neither of those approaches returns a static, authoritative ttl. Does anyone know of a node.js equivalent to the above dig command? Or a different way of getting the authoritative ttl value, perhaps another package or executing the dig command from node and parsing the results (ugh)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to (reliably) get the authoritative TTL value of a record, you must ask the authoritative name servers of that record. `dig` with the `+trace` flag does that, by recursing down from the root (and showing you the steps). I don't know if there is a node.js library that does that for you. If there isn't and you want to implement it yourself, you want to read [RFC 1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt), particularly section 4.3.2.

Comment: Thanks, Calle! Haven't been able to find a library, so guess I've got some reading/building to do.